# Distributive property of multiplication?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Like multiplication over addition is distributive , $a(b+c)= ab + ac$, could we say multiplication over multiplication is not distributive
$$\dfrac1a (bc)\ne \left(\dfrac1a\right)b *\dfrac 1a (c)?$$

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: I edited your question twice

Comment: It's dangerous to use $\neq$ this way. What is true that there **exists** some numbers $a,b,c$ such that $a(bc)\neq (ab)(ac).$ The expressions are sometimes equal - when $a(bc)=0$ or when $a=1.$

Comment: So, what you can say is if $a\neq 0,b\neq0, c\neq0$ and $a\neq1$ then $$abc\neq (ab)(ac).$$

Comment: We have that for $abc\neq 0$ $$ \require{cancel} \cancel{\dfrac1a} \cancel{(bc)}= \left(\dfrac1a\right)\cancel{b} \cdot \cancel{\dfrac 1a} \cancel{(c)} \iff 1=\frac1a \iff a=1$$